# Can't make Xcode 4 run a barely empty project using SDK 4.2 (runs fine in 4.3)

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-4.2, xcode4, ios4

I created a blank NavBar project and only touched a couple lines or so on one of the view controllers. I tested it fine in the 4.3 iPad and iPhone emulator but can't make it work for 4.2 at all. I get an error saying:

> The selected run destination is not valid for this action.

This is what I have on my project settings:

[image: Screenshot of my project settings]

Usually in XCode 3 that was all I needed to change but I guess I'm missing some setting in XCode 4.

What could this be?

Comment: Is this the settings for the project or the target?

Comment: Try looking at the target settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@pokstad, you are right. I was looking at the wrong place indeed!

Choosing the target and changing the SDk there did the trick.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I really had troubles with this and none of the hints helped.
Finally I got an error message that pointed to an old file in the build folder, in the end a simple clean did resolve my issues (shift+cmd+K). It compiled fine. So remember to clean your current build after you changed the build settings in Xcode4.
This may be obvious, but at that moment it wasn't obvious to me.